# Develop a web interface for custom embedded device

Tags: webserver, embedded-linux, webmin, luci

I have developed the hardware for a location tracker (basically reports its GPS coordinates via 3G mobile connection to a remote server)

This device is running Debian GNU/Linux on 512MB of RAM, and has an Ethernet port.

I would like to add a web interface to this device, to be able to see some device status indicators and to configure basic parameters, in the same fashion you would with any WiFi router nowadays.

I would prefer not to develop this web interface from scratch, and rather use an existing framework that provides a customizable implementation for something similar to a web interface configurator and status page.

I use [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org) and [LuCi](https://github.com/openwrt/luci/wiki/Installation) regularly, but I can't seem to find any possibility of using LuCi without OpenWrt. The two projects seem inexorably interlinked.

Another option might be [Webmin](https://webmin.com), but it seems to use plugins for existing services. Perhaps it makes sense to develop a plugin for Webmin, but I am afraid this might be bending the purpose of webmin too much.

I have found [this related question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984709/designing-web-interface-for-embedded-system), but it is unfortunately out-dated

**Can anyone recommend a framework for the purpose of developing a web interface for an embedded device**. Perhaps something like LuCi but flexible enough to be implemented in embedded devices other than OpenWrt.

Comment: There aren't really such frameworks (AFAIK) - since the interface is rendered usually by a desktop browser, you can use pretty much any framework you like. The embedded device will just run a lightweight webserver, and serve the static resources (maybe run php also...), but all the heavy lifting is done by the user's browser.

Comment: Have a look at [mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose)